# Getting value out of loop

Tags: java, android

I am trying to modify below code for my simple application needs. Since I am a beginner, sometimes it is hard to get some obvious for profi guys things. I want to get             sum += p.price; out of the loop because when I click button second time it doubles result. I know that : is conditional operator but can not get meaning of this statement (Product p : boxAdapter.getBox()). Probably if someone will explain or transfer into do..while it will be easy to understand.

```
public void showResult(View v) {

    String result = "Items in the basket: ";
    String sum_text = "For the sum: ";

    for (Product p : boxAdapter.getBox()) {

        if (p.box) {
            result += "\n" + p.name + "   " + p.price;
        }

        sum += p.price;

    }

    Toast.makeText(this, result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Toast.makeText(this, sum_text + sum, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Sorry, for bothering with simple questions.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html

Comment: where is sum defined? Can you not just do sum = 0 before the loop?

Comment: The expression in the for loop returns a collection of items where each item is denoted p. Then the sum of the items is accumulated and stored in sum. As mentioned above, the sum variable should be set to zero prior to the calculation done in the loop.

Comment: it should be defined inside method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (Product p : boxAdapter.getBox())
```

this loop will iterate through, boxAdapter.getBox() collection of Product type, store each instance into p, to convert into simple for loop, change it to like:

```
for(int i=0; i<boxAdapter.getBox().size(); i++)
{
    Product p=boxAdapter.getBox().get(i);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for unfolding this for me.

Answer (score 0):

`for (Product p : boxAdapter.getBox())` means you iterate over every Product object in the result of `boxAdapter.getBox()`.

If `boxAdapter.getBox()` for example returns a list containing 2 Product objects your loop will be executed 2 times and the first time `p` will be the first item from the list and the second time the second item from the list.